# Debugging Android (client - in physical smartphone device) and tomcat (server) on eclipse (localhost)

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, tomcat, client-server

How to debug an Android application (in physical smartphone device not emulator) and tomcat (server) on eclipse (localhost).

Context:

Android application (loggin-in for example) towards a tomcat server app in localhost.

For development-debugging with emulator works fine because Android runs on another subnet and reserves 127.0.0.1 for itself, the computer's localhost ip is changed to 10.0.2.2...

But, when I've tried with a physical smartphone connected via usb to my PC, I can debug the android app, but the request from the smartphone is not calling my tomcat on localhost using localhost:8080/... or 127.0.0.1:8080/...  The phone is trying to connect to the internet, not the subnet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved just using my intranet ip 192.168.2.1:8080/...